# On estimators that do not converge to a constant

Tags: distributions, estimation, inference

Say one had constructed an estimator $\hat{\mu}_n$ for a parameter $\mu$ and that such estimator had the property that

$$  \hat{\mu}_n \xrightarrow {d} X $$
where $X$ is a random variable with an associated distribution such that $\operatorname E[X] = \mu$ and $ \operatorname{Var}[X] = \sigma^2  > 0$. Although this estimator is not consistent I would still think it could be useful since as the sample size increases it would (on average) be a good estimate for the quantity $\mu$.

Does this kind of weak consistency have a name?  Has it been studied?

Comment: Do you have any example in mind?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Actually yes but the construction for the estimator I have in mind is a tad long...

Comment: What's wrong with "convergence in distribution", which is what I take your expression to mean?

Comment: @jbowman Absolutely nothing and yes that is what I mean. I was referring to the term "consistent" that is used in the statistical literature when talking about estimators, the convergence in distribution of estimators is not usually discussed and estimators that converge in distribution (not to a dirac delta distribution) are not called "consistent" even though It seems to me they might still be useful and worthy of study. I hope I have clarified my question and thanks for the question.